React useEffect cleanup function not undoing changes caused by React strict mode in development
This issue references to the fact that React intentionally remounts your components in development to find bugs.
I know I can turn off strict mode, but React doesn't recommend it. I'm just looking for a recommended approach to fix this.
I'm trying to build an Open Modal Component that closes either when the close button is clicked, or the user clicks outside the modal contents.
So, to implement the outside click closing of the modal, I'm using a useEffect hook that I want its callback function to only run when the isModalPopedUp state changes, and won't run on the initial render of the component. For this I use a custom hook:

import { useRef } from "react";

import { useEffect } from "react";

// This custom hook sets if a useEffect callback runs at initial render or not
export default function useDidMountEffect(argObject = {}) {
    /* 
    argObject = {
        runOnInitialRender: boolean,
        callback: () => void,
        dependencies: any[] // array of dependencies for useEffect
    }
    */
    const didMountRef = useRef(argObject.runOnInitialRender);

    // useEffect to run
    useEffect(() => {
        if (didMountRef.current) {
            // callback will run on first render if argObject.runOnInitialRender is true
            argObject.callback();
        } else {
            // callback will now run on dependencies change
            didMountRef.current = true;
        }
    }, argObject.dependencies); // only run if dependencies change
}

For the modal component, I split it into two components, the parent-modal that handles state logic:

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Modal from "./modal";
import useDidMountEffect from "./useDidMountHook";
import "./modal.css";

export default function ModalParent() {
    const [isModalPopedUp, setIsModalPopedUp] = useState(false);

    function handleToggleModalPopup() {
        setIsModalPopedUp((prevState) => !prevState);
    }

    function handleOnClose() {
        setIsModalPopedUp(false);
    }

    function handleOutsideModalClick(event) {
        !event.target.classList.contains("modal-content") && handleOnClose();
    }

    // add event listener for outside modal click using the useDidMountEffect hook
    useDidMountEffect({
        runOnInitialRender: false,
        callback: () => {
            // add event listener when modal is shown
            if (isModalPopedUp) {
                document.addEventListener("click", handleOutsideModalClick);
            } else {
                // remove event listener when modal is closed
                document.removeEventListener("click", handleOutsideModalClick);
            }

            // return a cleanup function that removes the event listener when component unmounts
            return () => {
                document.removeEventListener("click", handleOutsideModalClick);
            };
        },
        dependencies: [isModalPopedUp], // only re-run the effect when isModalPopedUp changes
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <button
                onClick={() => {
                    handleToggleModalPopup();
                }}>
                Open Modal Popup
            </button>
            {isModalPopedUp && (
                <Modal
                    header={<h1>Customised Header</h1>}
                    footer={<h1>Customised Footer</h1>}
                    onClose={handleOnClose}
                    body={<div>Customised Body</div>}
                />
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

and the main modal component:

export default function Modal({ id, header, body, footer, onClose }) {
    return (
        <div id={id || "modal"} className="modal">
            <div className="modal-content">
                <div className="header">
                    <span onClick={onClose} className="close-modal-icon">
                        &times; {/* an X icon */}
                    </span>
                    <div>{header ? header : "Header"}</div>
                </div>
                <div className="body">
                    {body ? (
                        body
                    ) : (
                        <div>
                            <p>This is our Modal body</p>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </div>
                <div className="footer">
                    {footer ? footer : <h2>footer</h2>}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

So, the problem is that React remounts the parent component after initial render, making the callback for the useDidMountEffect to immediately add the click event listener to the document element without having the isModalPopedUp state being changed to true by the "open modal" button click.
So, when clicking on the "open modal" button, isModalPopedUp is toggled to true but then is immediately changed to false due to the click event listener being added to the document prematurely. So, it eventually makes the modal unable to be opened by clicking the "open modal" button.
React.dev gives an easy fix by using the cleanup function returned by the useEffect callback to undo the changes from the remounting:

Usually, the answer is to implement the cleanup function.  The cleanup function should stop or undo whatever the Effect was doing. The rule of thumb is that the user shouldn’t be able to distinguish between the Effect running once (as in production) and a setup → cleanup → setup sequence (as you’d see in development).

My cleanup function removes the click event listener from the document element, but it still doesn't fix the problem.
For the styling of the modal, I'm using:

/** @format */

.modal {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 2rem;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #b19b9b;
    color: black;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 80%;
    animation-name: animateModal;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.close-modal-icon {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.5rem;
    right: 0.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.header {
    padding: 4px 10px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

.body {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    height: 200px;
}

.footer {
    padding: 4px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

@keyframes animateModal {
    from {
        top: -200px;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    to {
        top: 0;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}



is your end goal to have this close with a click outside of it, I think you may be able to use the useRef hook to do this in a much simpler way if that is what you are trying to accomplish

Yes. That's the end goal.

Based on the guidelines given by @justnut and @Mr. Hedgehog, I was able to come up with a working solution.
The issue is caused by the click event listener being set on the document element prematurely when the "open modal" button is clicked (due to the way the useEffect hook works).
So, when the "open modal" button is clicked, the event bubbles/propagates up to the document element, thereby unexpectedly triggering the handOutsideClick function.
The fix is therefore to stop the event propagation up to the document element by using the event.stopPropagation() method in the callback of the "open modal" button click event.
For checking whether the click was outside the modal, I used @justnut approach.
Based on @Mr. Hedgehog explanations, I returned a better cleanup function in the useEffect hook.
This is the overall modified code in the parent-modal component (the useDidMountEffect discarded):

/** @format */

import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import Modal from "./modal";
import "./modal.css";

export default function ModalParent() {
    const [isModalPopedUp, setIsModalPopedUp] = useState(false);

    function handleToggleModalPopup() {
        setIsModalPopedUp((prevState) => !prevState);
    }

    function handleOnClose() {
        setIsModalPopedUp(false);
    }

    function handleClickOutside(event) {
        if (modalRef.current && !modalRef.current.contains(event.target))
            handleOnClose();
    }

    // create modalRef for handling outside modal click events
    const modalRef = useRef(null);

    // create a useEffect for handling outside modal click events
    useEffect(() => {
        if (isModalPopedUp) {
            window.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
                handleClickOutside(event);
            });
        } else {
            // Remove the event listener when modal is closed
            window.removeEventListener("click", handleClickOutside);
        }

        // Cleanup: Remove the event listener when component unmounts
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("click", handleClickOutside);
        };
    }, [isModalPopedUp]);

    return (
        <div>
            <button
                onClick={(event) => {
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    // toggle modal popup state
                    handleToggleModalPopup();
                }}>
                Open Modal Popup
            </button>
            {isModalPopedUp && (
                <Modal
                    header={<h1>Customised Header</h1>}
                    footer={<h1>Customised Footer</h1>}
                    onClose={handleOnClose}
                    body={<div>Customised Body</div>}
                    modalRef={modalRef}
                />
            )}
        </div>
    );
}


and a little addition to the main modal component where I added the modalRef prop:

/** @format */

export default function Modal({ id, header, body, footer, onClose, modalRef }) {
    return (
        <div id={id || "modal"} className="modal">
            <div className="modal-content" ref={modalRef}>
                <div className="header">
                    <span onClick={onClose} className="close-modal-icon">
                        &times; {/* an X icon */}
                    </span>
                    <div>{header ? header : "Header"}</div>
                </div>
                <div className="body">
                    {body ? (
                        body
                    ) : (
                        <div>
                            <p>This is our Modal body</p>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </div>
                <div className="footer">
                    {footer ? footer : <h2>footer</h2>}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}


Help: If anyone can turn this into a runnable react stack snippet, it'd much appreciated. The modal component and css for styling is in the question above.

You shouldn't need the
} else {
// Remove the event listener when modal is closed
window.removeEventListener("click", handleClickOutside);
}
the cleanup function should take care of this for you
I would also recommend 'mousedown' over 'click', click I believe will handle the press and release, which may cause some problems, while mousedown is just the press.
I would also just not make Modal a component here, it doesn't seem like its going to be reused but if it is its good

If the modal isn't shown, no need to trigger the handleClickOutside() anymore with click events on the document element; the cleanup function helps when the component is removed when the modal is still shown. I need the user to press and release before the modal is popped up, that's why I'm using click.

As long as you know it’s all good :) Well since the dependency is isModalPopedUp the cleanup will run when it gets closed which makes the else unnecessary but you still need the if, if I am wrong about that everything looks good :)

I get your point, but I'm leaving the code that way.

This following will help you setup what you will need to handle the clicking outside of your Modal.
    const modalRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);

    const handleClickOutside = (e: MouseEvent) => {
       if (modalRef.current && !modalRef.current.contains(e.target as Node)){
         setIsModalOpen(false);
       }
    };


Along with this, you will need to set the reference and within a useEffect have something like this:
useEffect(() => {
   if(isModalOpen){
      window.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside)
   }
}, [isModalOpen]);


What's the commandBarRef?

lol sorry, that was just what it was in my code that I was referencing. updated now, let me know if you need any further clarifications

I've tried integrating your approach to the parent component, but still got the same result. Could you please try integrating it yourself and see if it works or needs some fixes?

can you edit the post to show me the current iteration so I can see

I think you misunderstand the concept of cleanup function. It's your responsibility to write state, effects and interaction in a way that when everything is remounted and all effects do their thing, you are back at square one. In your case, you attach event listener and change state, but then in cleanup you only remove listener and don't touch state. This means that you didn't cleaned all up.
Another thing here is that it would be much easier to implement without effects at all. Modal dialog is "modal", meaning that user actually can't interact with a page underneath it. Simple solution is to make an overlay above the visible content (it can be transparent if you want it "absent") and listen to the click on it (same one as on button). This way, to control a modal state you will need single boolean state variable and a single handler to change that variable.
